# npx webpack Unexpected token :

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use Webpack for the first time with Node and Babel (this is my first time using Babel as well) on Windows 10. I think I have everything configured properly, but it's giving me a cryptic error:
[image: error]
The same thing happens if I do `npx webpack --exec bable-node`.

In everything I've read about this, it gives a line number. I'm not sure what's the issue.

I have all of the files I thought were related to Node in a folder called "node", and all the other files in a folder called "src". I don't know if this is causing the issue. Here is the folder structure:

```
/node
    /config
    /node_modules
    .babelrc
    master-updated.sh
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    server2.js
    webpack.config.js
/src
    /model (this is has a bunch of js files, but I removed the references to them for now)
    /public
        /html
        /srcipts
        /stylesheets
            /css
            /scss
        /vue
.gitignore
```

`master-updated.sh` is a shell script for responding to a GitHub webhook.

Here is the beginning of `server2.js`:

```
'use strict';

process.env.NODE_CONFIG_DIR = './node/config';

const config = require('config'),
    babel = require('babel-core'),

    ejs = require('ejs'),

    util = require('util'),

    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    moment = require('moment'),
    plaid = require('plaid'),
    mariadb = require('mariadb'),

    fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),

    session = require('express-session'),

    exec = require('child_process').exec;

const GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID = '<REDACTED>';

const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const googleAuthClient = new OAuth2Client(GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID);

const APP_PORT = config.APP_PORT;
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: {
        app: ['./server2.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'server.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            test: '/\.js$/',
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is `.babelrc`:

`{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}`

And here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sage-savings",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "An app for easy budgeting.",
  "main": "server2.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config node/webpack.config.js",
    "start": "node node/server2.js"
  },
  "author": "Dakota Dalton",
  "repository": "https://github.com/1silvertiger/Sage",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.397.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "config": "^3.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^2.5.9",
    "express": "4.16.x",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "google-auth-library": "^3.0.1",
    "mariadb": "^2.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "plaid": "2.x.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole error including stack trace. The error message alone does not tell us enough.

Comment: @sdgluck That is the whole error.

Comment: The image you have shared only contains an error _message_. It is very likely the error also has a _stack trace_ beneath it (a bunch of lines with filenames). This is what we are after: the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any stacktrace. That's what makes it so cryptic and frustrating. I'll update the snip to show you.

Comment: See my updated answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These syntax problems are easily identified if you use an IDE which has syntax highlighting, for example [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). All I did was copy your config into a file and load it into VS Code.

1. You are incorrectly closing the regular expression used for `exclude`:

   ```
   exclude: /node_modules\,
   ```

   You must use a forward slash instead of a back slash:

   ```
   exclude: /node_modules/
   ```
2. You also need to wrap your loader in an object literal:

   ```
   loaders: [
       { // <= wrap in object literal
           test: '/\.js$/',
           loader: 'babel-loader',
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           query: {
               presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
           }
       }
   ]
   ```

Comment: @silvertiger Fair enough - you could re-enable it temporarily to catch these problems next time. I'll leave that part of the answer for others too.

Comment: I'm going to re-enable it as soon as I remember how to find it.